# Computing eucledian distance between vectors

Tags: r, csv

I don't understand how the dist() function works that computes the euclidean distance between two vectors. I created the simplest one dimensional vectors and I would like an explanation of the result I am getting. Here is the vector as an CSV file called test.csv:

```
Item Name   Attribute
Item 1      3
Item 2      5
```

Here is the code:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE)
dist(test, method = "euclidean")
```

Here is the output I get:

```
dist(test, method = "euclidean")
    1 2 2.828427
Warning message: In dist(test, method = "euclidean") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

The version of R is: Rx64 3.4.3

I expect the result to be 2 as opposed to 2.828427 because I assume that the euclidean distance is computed by the formula: `d = sqrt((xi - yi)^2)`.

Substituting the numbers from the test.csv file into the formula I get:

```
d = sqrt((3-5)^2) = 2
```

Comment: It is not computing the distance of `c(3, 5)`, see the output of `str(test)` in order to see what is being passed to `dist`.

Comment: I would guess is that you are getting that error as you are passing non-numeric data to `dist` - try omitting the first column from your calculation.

Comment: ps it is much easier for us to see what is going on with your data if you post the results of `dput(test)` . ty

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a matrix, it will consider your input to be `n` times an `m` dimensional vector, see:

```
dist(t(df[,c("Name","Attribute")])) # distance between the two columns
dist(df[,c("Name","Attribute")]) # distance between the two rows

sqrt((1-3)^2 + (2-5)^2) # distance between the two columns
sqrt((1-2)^2 + (3-5)^2) # distance between the two rows
```

I think this does what you want:

```
apply(df[,c("Name","Attribute")],1, function(x) {abs(x[1]-x[2])})
```